# Verilog - what is the difference in use between vertical bar (|) and "or"

Tags: verilog

When should I use "|" and when should I use "or"? I have noticed that the condition in always blocks uses "or" such as:

```
always @ (posedge clk or posedge reset)
```

while in if statements you use "|" such as:

```
if (condition1 | condition2)
```

Why must we use different operators? What other cases use "|" or "or"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There needs to be a way to distinguish between logical or (`||`), bitwise or (`|`) and event or `or`. The difference is clearer when you have signals A and B

```
wire [1:0] A,B;
always @(A | B) ... // waits for a change in the bit-wise result of A | B
always @(A || B) ... // waits for a change in the logical result of A | B
always @(A or B) ... // waits for a change either A's value or B value
```

Comment: I am still a little confused about the difference between "|" and "||". In what cases/examples would you get different results depending on if you used logical or versus bitwise or?

Comment: Assume A = `2'b10` and B = `2'b00`and B changes to `2'b01`.  The logical or `||` result remains unchanged `1'b1, whereas the bit-wise or `|` changes from `2'b10` to `2'b11`. Then, B changes to `2'b11`. There is not change in logical or, bit-wise or, but there is still an event on B.

Comment: As dave_59 has mentioned, if we have A and B as two wires each "x" bits wide, then the bit wise or `|` will give you a result which is also "x" bits wide. On the other hand, a logical or `||` of A and B will give you a `True` or `False` result or a 1-bit result.

Answer (score 3):

`|` is a bitwise 'or' operator.

`or` is used in the sensitivity list as an item separator (v95). `,` can be used instead of 'or' in v2k and system verilog.

`or` can also be a gate name in structural verilog.

`||` is a logical 'or' operation